# Scope in Javascript, using let

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
let king = 'John';

if(true) {
    let king = 'Sam';

    if(true) {
        let king = 'Ram';
        console.log(king);
        }
    }

if(true){
    console.log("This is second part:"+ king);
    }
```

output: 
Ram
This is second part: John;

Why in the second log its showing John, when the king is already changed to Ram?

Comment: Because `let` has block scope.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more, it's declared as a global on top, and the same variable is getting changed to 'Ram' in if block.

Comment: Inner scope declarations shadow outer scope declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been mentioned in the previous answers, variables declared using `let` are block scoped and that is why you are getting that result.

Just to mention that the same goes for `const`. And to see the difference, consider variables declared using `var` keyword, those are function scoped, so if you do something like this

```js
var king = 'John';

if (true) {
  var king = 'Sam';

  if (true) {
    var king = 'Ram';
    console.log(king);
  }
}

if (true) { console.log("This is second part:"+ king); }
```

You get `Ram` both times because the last assignment overwrites the first two ones (all of them are in the same scope), but if you wrap it in a function

```js
var king = 'John';

function foo() {
  if (true) {
    var king = 'Sam';

    if (true) {
      var king = 'Ram';
      console.log(king);
    }
  }
}

foo();

if (true) { console.log("This is second part:"+ king); }
```

You get the same result as with `let` keyword because you are creating a new scope for those variables wrapped by function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using let multiple times inside every if. If you declare "king" only once at the beginning this will work.

```
let king = 'John';

if (true) {
  king = 'Sam';

  if (true) {
    king = 'Ram';
  }
} 

console.log("This is second part:" + king);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because variables declared by **let** have their scope in the block. From the looks of it and the output you desire, you may want to use **var** instead of **let** i.e,

```
var king = 'John';
if(true) {
  var king = 'Sam';
  if(true) {
    var king = 'Ram';
    console.log(king);
  }
}
if(true){
  console.log("This is second part:"+ king);
}
```